# mPDF generating blank pdf when importing css

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tailwind-css, mpdf, php-8

When using PHP 8.1 and mpdf 8.1.2, when generating a PDF, the body of the resulting pdf is empty. While when I just output the HTML used in writehtml, I do get the full content including the css interpreted correctly.
However, when I comment out the `<style>{% include '@App/inlineStyles/pdf.css' %}</style>` part, it does render the PDF correctly, however (obviously) without the required styling.

I also tried seperately including both using 2 different writeHTML calls (with different modes for css). This resulted in the css not being applied (but the content being written).

The pdf.css file doesn't contain anything weird/invalid. It's partially based on tailwind and generated from .scss files.

I tried `new Mpdf(['debug'=>true])` and also tried to catch any mpdfexceptions, but there were none.

Can somebody help me out?

**EDIT:**
The reason for this happening is within CssManager.php that the entire css gets removed:

```
    // Remove CSS (tags and content), if any
    $regexp = '/<style.*?>(.*?)<\/style>/si'; // it can be <style> or <style type="txt/css">
    $html = preg_replace($regexp, '', $html);
```

**EDIT2:**
How am I supposed to include a file? I think I know the problem; I require the tailwind css component in my .css file which I'm including. The length of my .css file is 38601 lines (1000kb). The problem is in Mpdf/CssManager.php, line 481 (the code above). The return of the preg_replace is null because the file is too long.

In the past (with PHP 7.3 & an older version of mpdf) I did manage to include the tailwind css also into the mpdf writehtml. But in this version it does not work any longer.

My main question is, what is the best way to include the tailwind component? As I'm guessing that the length is what is causing $html to be null and therefore resulting in a blank page

(I'm not sure whether it would still be required to include a file (?))

Comment: Show your entire reproducible code, noone can help you unless they can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Did update. If a file is still required, please let me know what the best way is to upload this safely onto stackoverflow, which uploadserver to use. Thanks for your response either way :)

Comment: Not helpful. Isolate your problem by removing code not causing the issue. Not the library code, your (external) code. See MCVE/MRE https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean